# Regex match for a URL input

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex expression for a URL that matches if you include the protocol (https://), and host name (name and extension e.g youtube.com). i have included a regex 101 link below.

Where im struggling is trying to **not** match simply 'youtube' and also writing the syntax for matching https:// as a group.  I cant escape properly for the double forward slash or colon.

https://regex101.com/r/0KUyxu/5

```
/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]|[https:\//])$/gm
```

It should not match:

```
youtube
https://youtube
www.youtube
```

It should however match:

```
https://youtube.com
youtube.com
www.youtube.com
https://www.youtube.com
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is a character class notation `[https:\//]` But why not specify youtube in the pattern?

Comment: i cant specify 'youtube' directly as the url will be different everytime depending on the users input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems quite complex, this should work fine:

`^(https?:\/\/)?([0-z\-\.]+)\.([a-z]{2,})$`

and you'll also have:

- group 1 → protocol
- group 2 → domain name
- group 3 → domain extension

### Edit

To handle the case where it shouldn't match the `www.domainname`, you can use negative lookbehind like this:

`^(https?:\/\/)?([0-z\-\.]+)(?<!www)\.([a-z]{2,})$`

here the tester: https://regex101.com/r/0KUyxu/8

Comment: This is an elegant solution and makes a lot more sense, thank you, however what about the instance where it should not match www.youtube?

https://regex101.com/r/0KUyxu/7

Comment: yeah sorry I added a version with negative lookbehind to handle the `www` before the `.`

Answer (score 2):

[Tested in the chrome console.]

I Can't completely do what you asked for did something relative to that (I think so!)

```
function urlRegexTest(testUrl) {
var expression = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var url = testUrl;
console.log("URL ="+url);
var res = "";
if (url.match(regex)) {
    res = "Valid URL";
} else {
    res = "Invalid URL";
}
console.log(res);
}
```

```
Test inputs & outputs
```

urlRegexTest("godaddy.in")
URL =godaddy.in
Invalid URL

---

urlRegexTest("godaddy.com")
URL =godaddy.com
Invalid URL

---

urlRegexTest("www.godaddy.com")
URL =www.godaddy.com
Valid URL

---

urlRegexTest("https://godaddy.com")
URL =https://godaddy.com
Valid URL

---

urlRegexTest("http://godaddy.com")
URL =http://godaddy.com
Valid URL

---

urlRegexTest("http://godaddy.in")
URL =http://godaddy.in
Valid URL

---

urlRegexTest("http://sts.in")
URL =http://sts.in
Valid URL

---

urlRegexTest("godaddy.in")
URL =godaddy.in
Invalid URL

---

urlRegexTest("https://godaddy.in")
URL =https://godaddy.in
Valid URL

---

urlRegexTest("www.godaddy.in")
URL =www.godaddy.in
Valid URL

---

You can refer for more info about this question:-
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-url-using-regular-expression-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps for your example data it would suffice to check that the string does not start with `www.` and does not contain a dot anymore.

```
^(?!www\.[^.\r\n]*$)\S+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tbCL92/1)

Or a bit more specific, where you can specify the allowed characters using character classes and

```
^(?!www\.[^.\r\n]*$)(?:https?://)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!www\.[^.\r\n]*$)` Negative lookahead, assert the start does not start with `www.` without anymore dots
- `(?:https?://)?` Optionally match `http`, optional s and `://`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ any of the listed chars in the character class
- `(?:[.-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching either a `.` or `-` *(to prevent matching consecutive dots and hyphens if that should not be possible)*  and 1+ times any of the listed chars in the character class
- `\.[a-z]{2,}` Match `.` and 2 or more times a char a-z
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XOzq0I/1)

Answer (score 0):

For this case, try: [[a-zA-Z.://]+.com$](https://regex101.com/r/0KUyxu/6)

This expression matches a string of length one or more containing letters in the alphabet plus `.` , `:` ,  `/` before the `.com`. However, if the domain name contains any special characters, then this would fail.